# Is it possible to write a type predicate whose second argument is the key to the object it applies to?

Tags: typescript

Let's assume I have the following error thrown when the API returns a 400 error:

```
type ServerError = {
  status: string
};

type ServerErrorResponse = {
  response: {
    errors: ServerError[];
  };
};
```

To work with this response, I can write two predicate functions that look quite similar:

```
function hasResponseKey(res: unknown): res is { response: unknown } {
  return typeof res === 'object' && res !== null && 'response' in res;
}

function hasErrorsKey(response: unknown): response is { errors: unknown } {
  return typeof response === 'object' && response !== null && 'errors' in response
}
```

And finally do the following:

```
function isResponseServerErrorResponse(
  res: unknown
): res is ServerErrorResponse {
  return (
    hasResponseKey(res) &&
    hasErrorKey(res.responseJSON) &&
    Array.isArray(res.responseJSON.errors)
  );
}
```

This works, however it has a bit of a code repetition. I could avoid that by passing the key as an argument to one single predicate function. Is it possible to write a type predicate whose second argument is the key to the object it applies to?

Something like this:

```
function hasKey(res: unknown, key: string): res is { key: unknown } {
  return typeof res === 'object' && res !== null && key in res;
}
```

Comment: You mean something like https://tsplay.dev/WPzQLN?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Could you write it as a response so I can accept it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Smart! The alternative would be https://tsplay.dev/NV78qm. Yours is clever but I'm not sure if it's the most intuitive.